# Natural Deduction for TFL

Tags: logic, tautology

Is the proof below correct for the following premise?: ⊤ ⊢ (B → ¬B) → ¬B

1   B → ~B :AS

2       B :AS

3       ~B : → E1,2

4       ⊥

5       ~B :~I1-4

6           --

7       (B->~B)-> ~B :->I1-4

Comment: Here is a natural deduction proof checker: https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: You should cite the rule name and source lines for ⊥, and the source lines for your last -> should be 1-5; otherwise your proof looks fine -- well done!

Comment: @lemontree thank you!!